# Where can I specify how many sides 'Select Faces By Sides' uses?

Tags: selection-tools

I'm looking for non-quad faces in my mesh and I found someone mentioned Select Faces By Sides. I found that option on the Select menu and in the Help documentation, but I do not see where I can specify how many sides. I must be looking right at it, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with most operators in blender, you can access the operator options by either opening the side toolbar (<kbd>T</kbd>) in the 3D view or by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> immediately after running the operator:

[image]

Comment: That's it! Thanks very much. Will accept your answer as soon as it will allow me to.